# Changing Text in AngularJS App

Tags: angularjs, data-conversion

I am learning AngularJS. I have an app with a controller that looks like the following:

```
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.isOn = false;
  $scope.flip = function() {
    $scope.isOn = !$scope.isOn;
  }
}
```

My view has the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="flip()">{{isOn}}</button>
</div>
```

I want isOn to be a true/false value in my controller. However, in my view I want to show "On" if the flag is true. If the flag is false, I want to show "Off". How do I do that? I thought I could possibly use a filter. However, I didn't have any luck with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use poor mans ternary operator:

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
  <button ng-click="flip()">{{(isOn) && 'On' || 'Off'}}</button>
</div>
```

Demo 1 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/785/)**</kbd>

or (from angularjs > 1.1.5)

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlRead"> 
  <button ng-click="flip()">{{isOn ? 'On' : 'Off'}}</button>
</div>
```

Demo 2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/856/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to do the logic in the controller

html template:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="flip()">{{isOnLabel}}</button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
function myController($scope) {
    var isOn = false;
    $scope.isOnLabel= 'Off';
    $scope.flip = function() {
        isOn = !isOn;
        $scope.isOnLabel = isOn?'On':'Off';
    };
};
```

If you need isOn to be on the $scope then in the controller change isOn with $scope.isOn

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.isOn = false;
    $scope.isOnLabel= 'Off';
    $scope.flip = function() {
        $scope.isOn = !$scope.isOn;
        $scope.isOnLabel = $scope.isOn?'On':'Off';
    };
};
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/4H4vj/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?:` operator

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="flip()">{{isOn?"On":"Off"}}</button>
</div>
```

Just verify your version of Anugular supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) (though probably it's not worth it). That way you would have something like:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="flip()">{{isOn | toggleFilter}}</button>
</div>
```